# how to append dynamic data in jquery mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

i want to append dynamic data from other page in a section of a page. but it should not be with blink effect.
I used $.get method for this but it replace the whole page html. is there any solution for changing only section area without blink effect

Comment: Tried `.load()` http://api.jquery.com/load/ ?

Comment: When you use $.get, how are you appending the results to the current page?

Comment: .load() and $.get  works but the entire page blinks when it load/append data in it.